# How to restrict Textbox value with the max value on key events?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a text box i want to restrict that value for max value using key events

I try with the below code and its work fine

```
function validateRange(ele) {       
    if(ele.val() < 0 || ele.val() > 100){
        console.log('false');
    }else{
        console.log('true');
    }
}
$('.digit-validation').keyup(function(event){
    validateRange($(this));
});
```

HTML:

```
<form:input type="text" path="depth" cssClass="number inplace-textbox digit-validation" data-min="0" size="10" />
```

I would like `if(ele.val() < 0 || ele.val() > 100)` is stop keypress.

**Update:** I am trying to do range of values validation.

Comment: You want to *stop* someone entering text if they *haven't entered enough* text? Or am I misunderstanding the use of the `data-min` lower-boundary?

Comment: Any reason for not using `maxlength` attribute?

Comment: It can use with (. eg.99.99) so I can't use with maxlength.

Comment: What's the actual problem you're trying to solve? It seems like you're trying to solve your choice of a solution, rather than solving the actual problem you started with. What's your goal? See '[What is the XY problem?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/130770)'

Comment: @SopheaPhy: Are you trying to do max/min length validation (or) range of values validation (like user can enter number between 1 and 100)?

Comment: so you want to check if the value that was entered is between 0 to 100? or it's length between 0 to 100? because maxLenght check for the amount of characters that can be entered to the textbox

Comment: @SopheaPhy: I have added an **Update** section in the question based on your comments in one of the answers. It also allowed me to take back my down-vote :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd suggest that you try and use the HTML5 `input` type of `number`, with `min` and `max` attributes:

```
<input type="number" min="0" max="100" />
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/rK5e7/).

This allows the user to enter a number directly (using the keyboard, or copy/paste), and allows for control of the increments using the `step` attribute ([`step="2"`](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/rK5e7/1/), for example, will allow increments, or decrements, of 2 on every click of the spinner arrows).

If, however, you *must* use a non-number `input`:

```
Number.prototype.between  = function (a, b, inclusive) {
    var min = Math.min.apply(Math, [a,b]),
        max = Math.max.apply(Math, [a,b]);
    return inclusive ? this >= min && this <= max : this > min && this < max;
};

$('.digit-validation').keydown(function(event){
    var v = parseFloat(this.value + String.fromCharCode(event.which));
    return parseFloat(v).between(0,100,true);
});
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/rK5e7/2/).

Answer (score 2):

Why do you not use `maxlength` HTML attribute ?

```
<input type="text" maxlength="100" />
```

There is no need to use JS to achieve this.

Comment: If I input (99.99), the maxlength can't control.

Comment: @Harry: I am trying to do range of values validation.

Answer (score 1):

For your validation, you need 2 things :

1. check if the user enters a number
2. check if the user enters something between 0 and 100

For the 1st one, since you use jQuery, you can use [`$.isNumeric()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.isNumeric/).
For the 2nd one, you need to parse the value as integer thanks to [`parseInt()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt).

That would give you :

http://jsfiddle.net/tLwYX/

```
function validateRange(ele) {    
    var val = ele.val();
    if(!$.isNumeric(val) || parseInt(val,10) < 0 || parseInt(val,10) > 100){
        $('#result').html('false');
    }else{
        $('#result').html('true');
    }
}
$('.digit-validation').keyup(function(event){
    validateRange($(this));
});
```

Comment: parseFloat. he can also use decimals.

Comment: @RoyiNamir You're right, it'd be more precise. Nevertheless, it works with `99.99` and `parseInt` as well since it give `99`.